# How to declare an option which doesn't allow any argument using getopts

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, getopts

I'm trying to understand how we can configure options for a ksh script using getopts and I have found below details on [declaring options using getopts](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/appb_11.htm):

```
Use : for options that require arguments.
Use # for options that require numeric arguments.
Use :? and #? for options that allow arguments but don't require them.
```

But is it possible to declare an option that doesn't allow any argument and add textual description about the option?

Answer (score 0):

Different getopt()s do it differently. There are ones for different languages, even... which one?

Read The Fine Documentation! I'm sure you'll find assorted examples there, and as a bonus, faster than asking here and waiting for an answer.